# Put Java Threading Class into a separate class

Tags: java, multithreading

Consider following SWT code example:

http://dev.eclipse.org/viewcvs/index.cgi/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet151.java?view=co

How can I separate the inline defined class?

```
Thread thread = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            ...
        }
    };
```

I want to define a separate class which updates the table just like it does here. How do I pass the list back to the table? Example code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just create a `class` which `extends Thread`.

```
public class Task extends Thread {
    public void run() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

and create it as follows:

```
Task task = new Task();
```

The normal practice is however to implement [`Runnable`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html):

```
public class Task implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Or if you want a `Thread` which returns a result, implement [`Callable<T>`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html) where `T` represents the return type.

```
public class Task implements Callable<String> {
    public String call() {
        // ...
        return "string";
    }
}
```

Both can be executed using the [`ExecutorService`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html).

Comment: That's indeed a better practice, or maybe even `Callable<T>` if you want a result. That was however not his question.

Answer (score 4):

I would not create a class that extends Thread.  It's more likely that you'll have a class that implements Runnable and provides access to private data members:

```
public class YourTask implements Runnable
{
    private ResultClass result;

    public void run() { }

    public ResultClass getResult() { return result; }
}
```

Have a look at java.util.concurrent packages and the new FutureTask.  I think that's a better bet.

Comment: If you want to return a result, also consider Callable instead of Runnable.

Answer (score 1):

You can work passing parameters or setting globally visible attributes, example:

```
class Foo
{
  public static String baz = "baz";
  private String bar = "bar";

  void startThread()
  {
    MyThread thread = new MyThread(bar);

    thread.start();
  }
}

class MyThread extends Thread
{
  String ref;

  MyThread(String ref)
  {
    this.ref = ref;
  }

  public void run()
  {
    // it can work with passed parameter
    System.out.println(ref);

    // but also with globally visible variables
    System.out.println(Foo.baz);
  }
}
```